# Ext.JS 6: How to set value in a grid cell

Tags: datagrid, extjs6-classic

When the user is editing the value of a grid cell and clears the value, I'd like to be able to set the value of that cell to a default value and have the cell marked as dirty if the original value wasn't the default. Essentially, if the user clears a cell's value, I'd like the cell to end up with the default value and have grid behave as though the user set the cell to that value.

Is there any way that I can do that? (I don't want to simply delete the row and add it in again with the same values, because I want to preserve all of the dirty flags in the row (including updating the one for the edited cell).) We're using Ext.JS 6.0.2 Classic.

Comment: I see 2 separate tasks:
1. Use the cellediting plugin edit event to check if the input text is empty and put your default value
2. Mark the cell as dirty - do you work with data models? If yes, set the defaultValue property for that field